# Trying to install amd radeon hd 7450 driver on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: installation, drivers

I am brand new to Ubuntu and have been trying for hours to download this driver. Every time I install amd catalyst center I can't do anything with it and it gives me an error code. I need to put this driver on their tonight because I'm supposed to ship it to a customer tomorrow. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is more a suggestion than an answer;

There is a known bug in Ubuntu 12.04 release (LTS) where your graphical driver is listed as "unknown" ( Visit system settings / Details / Graphics ).

I had the problem with my AMD Radeon graphic card on 12.04 and I couldn't get any proprietary drivers to work. Switching to Ubuntu 13.10 solved the problem.

I suggest you try clean installation with new Ubuntu (burn 13.10 ISO image on a DVD and reinstall).